# Enabling login button using RxJava2 on Android with JDK8

Tags: rx-android, rx-java2

I want to enable the login button when the username and password are long enough, using RxJava2, but I am getting errors.

```
final Button loginButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.loginbutton);
final TextView usernameField = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.username_logindialog);

Observable<Boolean> userNameValid = RxTextView.textChangeEvents(usernameField)
        .map(e -> e.text())
        .map(inputText -> inputText.length() > 4);

final TextView passwordField = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.password_logindialog);
Observable<Boolean> passwordValid = RxTextView.textChangeEvents(passwordField)
        .map(e -> e.text())
        .map(inputText -> inputText.length() > 7);

Observable<Boolean> registerEnabled =
        Observable.combineLatest(userNameValid, passwordValid, (a,b) -> a && b);
registerEnabled.registerObserver( enabled -> loginButton.setEnabled(enabled));
```

For both sections where you see `map(inputText` this is the error:

[image]

And the error for `a && b` is

[image]

There are other errors but I think the first two errors are the root cause, but I don't see what I should use instead of `Observable.combineLatest` now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this

```
emailChangeObservable = RxTextView.textChangeEvents(email);
passwordChangeObservable = RxTextView.textChangeEvents(password);

// force-disable the button
submitButton.setEnabled(false);

Observable.combineLatest(emailChangeObservable, passwordChangeObservable, 
                                        (emailObservable, passwordObservable) -> {
    boolean emailCheck = emailObservable.text().length() >= 3;
    boolean passwordCheck = passwordObservable.text().length() >= 3;
    return emailCheck && passwordCheck;
}).subscribe(aBoolean -> {
    submitButton.setEnabled(aBoolean);
});

// submit button will only be clickable if both forms have more than 3 characters each
```

[Check here for source](https://gist.github.com/cesarferreira/510aa2456dc0879f559f#login-form-rxbinding)

Comment: Thank you.  I just had to put rx.Observable.combineLatest and it compiles.